# How to using replace in select query? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
public function getList()
{
    $query =  self::join('master_datas','master_datas.id','=','users_banks.bank_id')
        ->orderBy('account_name')
        ->findAll([
                    'users_banks.*',
                    'master_datas.name',
                    DB::raw('replace(master_datas.information->logo, \'"\', "")')
            ]);
    return $query;
}
```

So, I have field information. Field information in the form json like this :

```
{"logo": "icon-chelsea.png", "branch": "london", "owner": "chelsea"}
```

When I call `information->logo`, the result : `"icon-chelsea.png"`.

I want to remove the double quotes. I tried to like my code above, using replace. But it did not work

I had add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` too. But, it's the same

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: When you say you want to `remove double quotes`. How did they get stored in the database that way? Fix the entry point, not the exit point. Further, strings should always be single/double quote encapsulated, if you want the constant representation of the value then that's something completely different.

Comment: How are you 'calling' `information->logo`?

Comment: Surely that is a JSON String? If you `json_decode()` it, it will not have the double quotes any more. But if you remove the double quote manually, it will not be a valid JSON String any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eloquent you can [create a mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to store `logo` string without double quotes:

```
public function setLogoAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['logo'] = str_replace('"', '', $value);
}
```

If you get data from somewhere else use [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) when you're getting the data:

```
public function getLogoAttribute($value)
{
    return str_replace('"', '', $value);
}
```